# Spring boot 3.2.1 properties binding

Tags: spring-boot

I has dependencies on library which has

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.web.auth")
@Getter
public class WebAuthConfigurationProperties {
  private final String endpoint;
  private final String loadBalancingPolicy;
  private final KeyConfiguration key;
  private final boolean tracingEnabled;
  private final Token token;
  private final RetryPolicies retryPolicies;
  ...
}
```

```java
@AutoConfiguration(after = WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class WebAuthAutoConfiguration {

  @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
  @Import({AuthConfiguration.class})
  @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "foo.web.auth.enabled", havingValue = "true")
  protected static class WebAuthEnabledAutoConfiguration {}

  @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
  @Import({AuthDisabledConfiguration.class})
  @ConditionalOnProperty(
      value = "foo.web.auth.enabled",
      havingValue = "false",
      matchIfMissing = true)
  protected static class WebAuthDisabledAutoConfiguration {}
}
```

```yaml
foo:
  web:
# It should be turned on after the new Spring Boot 3.2.1 becomes available.
# Issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38556
    auth:
      enabled: true
      endpoint: https://auth-headless.auth:8443
      token:
        fakeAuth: true
```

after upgrading to Spring boot 3.2.1
I'm getting

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'foo.web.auth-com.tink.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.auth.WebAuthConfigurationProperties':
> Could not bind properties to 'WebAuthConfigurationProperties' :
> prefix=foo.web.auth, ignoreInvalidFields=false,
> ignoreUnknownFields=true

It looks like `@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "foo.web.auth.enabled", havingValue = "true")`
not works. I thought that it is related to [spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38556) however after move to Spring boot 3.2.1 and Spring framework 6.1.2 I still get te same exception.

I expect that properties binding will work as previous with Spring boot 3.1.5

Comment: Have you tried to make `WebAuthConfigurationProperties` a record?

Comment: hi @DirkDeyne, nope, what I see inner classes use Lombok Value annotation and in the constructor are some DefaultValue annotations. However, the enabled field is not a part of this class only exists as

@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "foo.web.auth.enabled", havingValue = "true")

Comment: @YassineAbainou please make a new question, this question does not respect [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add setters : @Setter